# The image of a linear map between Frechet spaces is either the whole space or nowhere dense.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that The image of a linear map between Frechet spaces is either the whole space or nowhere dense. Clearly, I want to use the open mapping theorem. Suppose I am given a linear map $T: X \to Y$ between two Frechet spaces. But how?

Comment: It's not true. The image is either the whole space or meagre, but it can be dense.

Comment: As @DanielFischer says... and this failure can easily occur already for Hilbert spaces. For example, map $\ell^2\to \ell^2$ by $e_i\to e_i/i$, with standard orthonormal basis $e_i$...